# Terabyte size archive storage per day

Tags: oracle, plsql, archive, ddl, dml

I'm working on Oracle DB.
Archive storage up to TB levels per day. I need to fix this.
How to detect the expressions (dml + ddl) that cause the most change in the database?
You can check with this image.

[image: archived file size per day]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't think there is a way to directly measure the amount of archivelog space generated per statement, there are several simple queries that can measure things that are strongly correlated with archivelog space.

Use the view `GV$SQL` to find the non-SELECT SQL statements that have used the most time. The longest-running DML and DDL statements will often be the ones that write the most data. In my experience, just by looking at the results from this query, one of the SQL statements will stick out as the culprit.

```
select round(elapsed_time/1000000) seconds, gv$sql.*
from gv$sql
where command_type <> 3 --ignore SELECT statements.
order by seconds desc;
```

Use the view `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` to find the SQL statements that have generated the most physical writes in the past day. These results may also be misleading because direct-path writes will not generate REDO and archivelog data. But the chances are good that the culprit is in the top of the results from this query. (This view requires licensing the diagnostics pack - it's part of AWR.)

```
select sql_id, round(physical_write_bytes_total/1024/1024) mb, dba_hist_sqlstat.*
from dba_hist_sqlstat
where (snap_id, dbid) in
(
    --Snapshots in the last 24 hours.
    select snap_id, dbid
    from dba_hist_snapshot
    where begin_interval_time >= sysdate - interval '240' hour
)
order by dba_hist_sqlstat.physical_write_bytes_total desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is log mining pl/sql , you can turn on in oracle feature, the sql can see the content of archivelog, then you can find out , what is generate all these archivelog.

see following link(but you need to in dba role to enable and tracing the content of archivelogs)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm

scott

Comment: we should see the query you used to produce your evidence.  Also, if you would show the _time_ as well as the date, it would help you narrow down what you are looking for when you start reporting from data miner.

Answer (score 0):

This one will give you a graphical view of when log-switches are happening throughout the day. https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/log_files.html

```
set echo on
/*
Look for anomalies in log switch frequency and
switch frequencies greater than 12 per hour.
*/

set echo off
select
  to_char(first_time,'MMDD') MMDD,
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'00',1,0)),'999') "00",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'01',1,0)),'999') "01",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'02',1,0)),'999') "02",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'03',1,0)),'999') "03",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'04',1,0)),'999') "04",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'05',1,0)),'999') "05",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'06',1,0)),'999') "06",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'07',1,0)),'999') "07",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'08',1,0)),'999') "08",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'09',1,0)),'999') "09",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'10',1,0)),'999') "10",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'11',1,0)),'999') "11",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'12',1,0)),'999') "12",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'13',1,0)),'999') "13",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'14',1,0)),'999') "14",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'15',1,0)),'999') "15",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'16',1,0)),'999') "16",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'17',1,0)),'999') "17",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'18',1,0)),'999') "18",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'19',1,0)),'999') "19",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'20',1,0)),'999') "20",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'21',1,0)),'999') "21",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'22',1,0)),'999') "22",
  to_char(sum(decode(to_char(first_time,'HH24'),'23',1,0)),'999') "23"
from
  v$log_history
group by to_char(first_time,'MMDD')
order by 1;
```

Best of luck!